# How to load an html div with the text from another html page?

Tags: jquery

I have two html pages say text.html and display.html. The file text.html is having text in it. I want to load the text content of the text.html file to the display.html .How can i make it using jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
$('#div_id').load('text.html');.
```

Reference:  [jQuery load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `iframes` to dispaly html page with in that page

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following jquery load method: Explained with example at below link:

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

.load( url [, data] [, complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)] )
Description: Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.
http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

See `if you are on display.html` and `when document.ready() fires` below will be the possibilities you could have to do.

This way `load all the contents from the page1.html`

```
$('body').load('text.html');
```

and this one will load a specific div's content to the desired place of the current document.

```
$('#my_div').load('text.html #targetDiv');
```

`suppose` you have a `div with id of my_div` on `display.html` and `you want to load a specific content` from the `text.html page` then the above script will give you the desired results.